# ChatBot PHP - Facebook Messenger

Tags: php, http-request, facebook, chatbot

Olá, tudo bem? Estou criando um chatbot mas estou com problemas na requisição HTTP (POST).

Quando chamo uma função para enviar o POST ao Facebook Messenger me parece que entra em loop e começa a enviar todos os posts. Gerando isso como resultado:

[image: ChatBot]

Vejam o código principal (index.php) que chama a função:

```
include 'Banco.php';
include 'Envio.php';
$banco = new Banco();
$envio = new Envio();

switch ($banco->getSecao($sender_id)) {
    case 0:
        //APRESENTACAO E PEDE CPF
        $envio->apresentacao($sender_id);
        break;
    case 1:
        //BOAS VINDAS E PEDE CPF
        $banco->setSecao($sender_id, 2);
        $envio->boasvindas($sender_id);
        break;
    case 2:
        //EXIBE RASTREIO            
        $banco->setSecao($sender_id, 3);
        $envio->pedidos($sender_id);
        break;
    case 3:
        //PEDE CODIGO DE RASTREIO
        $banco->setSecao($sender_id, 4);
        $envio->tracking($sender_id);
        break;
    case 4:
        //AGRADECE O USO PEDE CPF E COLOCA A SECAO EM 2
        $banco->setSecao($sender_id, 2);
        $envio->agradecimento($sender_id);
        break;
}
```

O Bot deveria enviar o POST apenas da "seção" que é retornada do Registro. Porem ele vai entrando em todos. Já tentei deixando apenas um case. ele fica enviando esse case várias vezes. Veja um exemplo da class Envio:

```
private function send($dados){            
        $url = $this->apiUrl . '?access_token=' . $this->access_token;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        $params = http_build_query($dados);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
        $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        return $server_output;
    }

    public function apresentacao($idClient){
        $responseJSON = array(
            "recipient" => array(
                "id" => $idClient
            ),
            "message" => array(
                "text" => "Olá, eu sou o Onex, tudo bem?\nQue legal te ver por aqui! Posso te ajudar a rastrear algum pedido?"
            )
        );
        $response = $this->send($responseJSON);

        $responseJSON = array(
            "recipient" => array(
                "id" => $idClient
            ),
            "message" => array(
                "text" => "Pra começar, vou precisar de seu CPF ou CNPJ:"
            )
        );
        $response = $this->send($responseJSON);
    }
```

Comment: ele realmente entra em todos os cases? não está simplesmente executando as funções? ja tentou por um echo em cada case pra ver se realmente está entrando nos cases? Se estiver entrando em casa um, há algo de errado com o parametro passado dentro do switch

Comment: @AndersonHenrique obrigado pela resposta. Removi o Switch e deixei apenas a parte de apresentação, mesmo assim ele enviou a apresentação várias vezes acredito que erro esteja na classe Envio, mas não estou conseguindo identificar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Venho compartilhar a solução.

Comecei a gravar em txt de todo post que era enviado, e reparei que o próprio facebook gera o loop, porem como não é o meu Bot que esta enviando o campo mensagem no JSON esta em branco, então fiz uma validação neste campo:

```
$message = isset($input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text']) ? $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text']: 'vazio' ;
```

E antes de ativar o switch eu valido:

```
if($message != 'vazio'){
```

E assim funcionou corretamente e acabou com os loops.

Muito obrigado e abraços!